# updating with ajax, undefined index

Tags: ajax, sql-update

I am attempting to build a theme-builder for the vote script I've been working on. I am trying to make it so you can view a preview and thus don't want the page to reload. I'm pretty new to AJAX, everything seems to work if I bypass it.

Problem is when I call the php file to update my database I am getting errors

HTML FILE: (all the inputs are actually in the index.php, but for the sake of room didn't include it here)

```
 <div id="theme" name="theme" class="theme">
      <form class="css_form">
            <table>
               <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="center"><label>Map Navigation Color</label></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="center"><input type="text" id="map_navigation" name="map_navigation" class="colorwell" value="#ffffff" /></td>
                </tr>    
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="center"><label>Test It</label></td>
                    <td align="left" valign="center"><input type="button" value="preview" onClick="getTheme();"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
 </div>
```

AJAX FILE (theme_builder.js)

```
function getTheme(str)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("theme").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

    var button_style = document.getElementById('button_style').value;
    var div_grad_1 = document.getElementById('div_grad_1').value;
    var div_grad_2 = document.getElementById('div_grad_2').value;
    var gradient_direction = document.getElementById('gradient_direction').value;
    var map_0 = document.getElementById('map_0').value;
    var map_100 = document.getElementById('map_100').value;
    var map_selected = document.getElementById('map_selected').value;
    var map_outline = document.getElementById('map_outline').value;
    var map_navigation= document.getElementById('map_navigation').value;
    var queryString =
        "button_style=" + button_style +
        "&div_grad_1=" + div_grad_1 +
        "&div_grad_2=" + div_grad_2 +
        "&gradient_direction=" + gradient_direction +
        "&map_0=" + map_0 +
        "&map_100=" + map_100 +
        "&map_selected=" + map_selected +
        "&map_outline=" + map_outline +
        "&map_navigation=" + map_navigation;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "theme_builder.php?"+queryString, true);
    xmlhttp.send();  
}
```

And Finally the php file (theme_builder.php

```
<?php
    include('../../connection.php');

    $button_style = ($_GET['button_style']);
    $div_grad_1 = ($_GET['div_grad_1']);
    $div_grad_2 = ($_GET['div_grad_2']);
    $gradient_direction = ($_GET['gradient_direction']);
    $map_0 = ($_GET['map_0']);
    $map_100 = ($_GET['map_100']);
    $map_selected = ($_GET['map_selected']);
    $map_outline = ($_GET['map_outline']);
    $map_navigation = ($_GET['map_navigation']);
    $id='2';

    $update_settings = "UPDATE vs_vote_settings SET 
                        button_style = ?,
                        div_grad_1 = ?,
                        div_grad_2 = ?,
                        gradient_direction = ?,
                        map_0 = ?,
                        map_100 = ?,
                        map_selected = ?,
                        map_outline = ?,
                        map_navigation = ?
                            WHERE id=?";

    $query_update_settings = $conn->prepare($update_settings);
        if(!$query_update_settings)
            {
                die ("error" .$conn->errorInfo());
            }
    $query_update_settings->execute(array($button_style, $div_grad_1, $div_grad_2, $gradient_direction, $map_0, $map_100, $map_selected, $map_outline, $map_navigation, $id));

$conn = null;
?>
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Notice: Undefined index: div_grad_2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: gradient_direction in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: map_0 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: map_100 in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: map_selected in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: map_outline in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: map_navigation in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\status201\applications\201vote\theme_builder.php on line 12
```

Note that button_style and div_grad_1 are not throwing errors, but the rest are. I can't find an error, but I would think its with my ajax file. I followed the tutorial from [Tizag](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-mysql-database.php) For the Ajax file and tried to modify it to my needs...

Any help would be very appreciated, I know there is a ton of code here, but I've been stumped for a while now.

Thanks

Comment: try doing print_r($_GET) just to see if all of the variables are getting passed through correctly. Also the first part of var queryString = starts with an & shouldnt it just be button_style=

Comment: I get this Array ( [button_style] => 1 [div_grad_1] => )
So its not passing all the information. Caught the & issue already will make an edit in my post. Thank you though

Comment: So is all the information getting through or not? I recommend you use POST rather than GET. have you got any javascript errors when you click the button?

Comment: just said: not all info getting to the php file. Not seeing any js errors...doesn't mean they're not there...new to ajax. I'll have to find a tut using POST with ajax. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Are you using a JS framework like jQuery or does it have to be native javascript?

Comment: I use jQuery for other elements on my page, but I'm not great with it.

Comment: try using something like $.post('url to post to', {variable:data, variable2}, function(data){ /success stuff here }); full explanation is here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Try use isset in theme_builder.php

```
$div_grad_1 = (isset($_GET['div_grad_1'])) ? $_GET['div_grad_1'] : "";
```

Comment: Hi George, unfortunately when using this I get no errors, however it also doesn't update anything in the db after button_style. Thanks though

Comment: In theme_builder.js 1-line:"function getTheme(str)"
remove "str", because in index file you call the function without argument 'onClick="getTheme();"'